OpenFeign/Feign with JAX-RS support for BeanParam only works on paper. Change my mind
I am trying to use OpenFeign/Feign to latch onto my JAX-RS based REST API. In most cases I use @BeanParam POJOs to capture all @PathParam, @QueryParam, etc. parameters. Unfortunately, Feign fails to produce a request that actually expands the parameters within the POJO correctly
I've extensively stepped through Feign's internal code and I don't find ANY clue in Feign's RequestTemplate/QueryTemplate/Template processing code that it actually can expand the BeanParam fields properly.
That leads me to the conclusion that the support for aggregated params like BeanParams is only there on paper. Anybody able to prove me wrong?
This is a code snipped that more or less matches what's tested in OpenFeign/Feign/jaxrs2/src/test...
    public interface RestInterface {
        @GET
        @Path("/")
        void beanCall(@BeanParam BeanParamInput beanParam);

        public class BeanParamInput {
            @QueryParam("query")
            String query;

            @HeaderParam("X-Custom-Header")
            String header;
        }
    }

I expect this @BeanParam-annotated parameter to be expanded into query and header elements in the RequestTemplate, when I'm running the following code:
        RestInterface client = Feign.builder()
            .contract(new JAXRS2Contract())   // Use JAX-RS annotations
            .target(RestInterface.class, "https://your-api-base-url");

        client.beanCall( new RestInterface.BeanParamInput() );

The JAXRS2Contract's registerParamAnnotations() method correctly identifies the parameter as @BeanParam, iterates over the fields, and adds path/query/header/form params to the MethodMetadata's RequestTemplate.
However nowhere in the request processing code does any expansion of the POJO take place.

in RequestTemplateFactoryResolver.create(Object... argv), a RequestTemplate object is created. JAXRS2Contract's registerParamAnnotations provides the correct params, but they're all set to the reference to argv[0] which is the full BeanParam object itself.
in RequestTemplate.resolve(Map<String,?> variables) I expect the field's values to be extracted properly. But right where it should happen (e.g. queryTemplate.expand(variables)), it's just setting up the default value handling via Template.expand(Map<String,?> variables) which resolves the variables as SimpleExpression
SimpleExpression.expand(Object variable, boolean encode) is just calling variable.toString() instead of accessing the POJO's Bean property.

And that's it. There's no way to extend Expression as it's package-private. And there's no configuration that would change Feign's RequestTemplate's argv expansion behavior.
